# How can I search a concatinated string in the where clause of a linqdatasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am looking to search the Full name in my profile class.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I get: Profile.FullName has no supported translation to SQL.

linq partial class:

```
partial class Profile
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<Profile, string>> expFullName = p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName;
        public static readonly Func<Profile, string> funcFullName = expFullName.Compile();

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return funcFullName(this); }
        }
    }
```

Datasource code:

```
    <asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" ID="someSource" ContextTypeName="MyContext" TableName="Images" 
Where='Approved == true && CategoryID = 2 && (@searchTerm = "" || Profile.FullName.Contains(@searchTerm))'>
        <WhereParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter Name="searchTerm" ControlID="txtSearch" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I do want to note that the below solution works.  But I would like to have a derived property for FullName and use it unconditionally.  Is that even possible?

```
(Profile.FirstName + " " + Profile.LastName).Contains(@searchTerm)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because it can be translated to SQL:

```
(Profile.FirstName + " " + Profile.LastName).Contains(@searchTerm)
```

This will not work because FullName is not a mapped to a column in SQL:

```
(Profile.FullName).Contains(@searchTerm)
```

Comment: I Understand that but what I want to do is have an expression on the linq class itself that knows to translate 'FullName' to 'FirstName + " " + LastName' when it's used in a query.  Don't know if its possible so thought I'd ask :)